# PostgreSQL - Before Update Trigger determine which columns were updated

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I have a table with many columns.
Need to find which columns value have changed.
I am using the following code. I am having a performance problem.

Can I do this with a different method?

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mytable()
      RETURNS trigger AS $$
    DECLARE
      _rec record;
    BEGIN
      FOR _rec IN
        SELECT
          o.key
          , o.value AS old_value
          , n.value AS new_value
        FROM json_each(to_json(new)) n
          INNER JOIN json_each(to_json(old)) o ON o.key = n.key
      LOOP
        IF (_rec.old_value::text IS DISTINCT FROM _rec.new_value::text) THEN
          /* 
             field name: _rec.key, 
             old values: _rec.old_value, 
             new value : _rec.new_value
          */
        END IF;
      END LOOP;

      RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: any other possible solution in plpgsql are a variations of your method, and the performance will be similar. Maybe PLPerl or PLPython can be better language for this purpose. The best performance you can take with C extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will perform performance tests with C extension.